# How to get data in sql according to customer number

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a query I completed half of it but stuck on the other half.

I have a table ##Table1 in which I have below columns

```
CusNbr  Ind  Acctnbr
  1      O     10
  2      I     10
  3      U     10
  4      O     20
  5      I     20
  6      O     30
  7      U     30
  8      I     40
  9      I     40
  10     O     50
  10     I     50
  10     I     60
```

Now till cusnbr 9 my code is working fine. Below is the code

```
Select * 
from ##Table1 
where cusnbr not in 
  (
    Select DISTCINT t1.cusnbr   
    from ##Table1 t1 
    join ##Table1 t2 on t1.Acctnbr=t2.Acctnbr 
    where (t1.Ind='I' or t1.Ind='U') and t2.Ind='O'
   )
```

which give me below output

```
CusNbr  Ind  Acctnbr
  1      O     10

  4      O     20

  6      O     30

  8      I     40
  9      I     40
```

But I want output like below

```
CusNbr  Ind  Acctnbr
  1      O     10

  4      O     20

  6      O     30

  8      I     40
  9      I     40
 10      O     50
 10      I     60
```

Any help will be appreciated Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You are not getting CusNbr 10 because your where clause eliminates it due to it having one record with an IND = 'O'.

Comment: Can you describe, in words, what you want to achieve with the I's, O's and U's please?

Comment: @JM_@schmocken yes I know but how to get this 10 customer also that my query.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT distinct t1.*

FROM
#Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN #Table1 t2 
    on t1.Acctnbr = t2.Acctnbr 
    and t1.Ind <> t2.Ind

WHERE
((t1.Ind <> 'I' and T2.Ind <> 'O')
and t1.Ind <> 'U')
or t2.Ind is null
```

Comment: Let me know how you get on, if no joy, then I would appreciate you script to build Table1

Comment: I have now tried this against your Table1 and achieve the desired output

Comment: can u tell me if I have customer 10 ind 'u' acc 20 and cus 10 ind 'I' and acc 21 then how to select also please explain what we are doing here after  where condition